# What are these characters appearing in my VSCode's WSL2 terminal when running rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

## Edit: 2021/05/12

The problem resolved itself after doing a full restart of my PC.  I'll revisit this question when/if I can recreate the issue.

### Problem

When running `rails c` from VSCode's integrated terminal, each new command line prepends a set of garbage characters that I have to delete.

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 4481
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.3.2)
irb(main):001:2> ^[[7;1R^[[7;1R
```

### Notes

Seems to be specific to my VSCode configuration? This problem does not occur when running in a separate Windows Terminal instance.

Does not occur when running `python` and `node` shells.

### Setup

I am using

- WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- VSCode integrated terminal w/ WSL remote enabled
- ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 6.1.3.2

Comment: Try checking your typing key structure you set from your setting/preferences. Sometime this happens when we change from English keyboard to something else.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't find any other forum post that addresses this. It happened a couple vscode updates ago but can't exactly tell when. It's very annoying.

Comment: @HirenBhalani I can't seem to find the setting you're referring to.

Comment: Are you linux or Mac?

Comment: @HirenBhalani Windows VSCode

Comment: Do you have any other language added for typing in your computer or any app that provides different keyboard structure for different languages?
@cmitch419